# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL when trying to link Spring boot app with database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am making this for a project after an exercise we made in class. I made an empty scheme in MySQL workbench with the name "fifa".

this is the beginning of the error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table Wedstrijd (id varchar(255) not null auto_increment, dag integer not null, landen tinyblob, uur integer not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
```

This is the quased by

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect column specifier for column 'id'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

This is my PersistenceJPAConfig class, the class is in the same package as the controllers where I call the data.

```
package com.spring.WorldCup;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

 @Bean
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setDataSource(dataSource());
      em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "domain" });

      JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

      return em;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource(){
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
      //achter3306/ meot de naam van de databank
      dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fifa?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
      dataSource.setUsername( "root" );
      dataSource.setPassword( "root" );
      return dataSource;
   }

  
   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
      return transactionManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }

   Properties additionalProperties() {
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
      //properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
      return properties;
   }
}
```

The annotation in the comment caused the error:

```
@Entity
public class Wedstrijd {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
//    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id; //unieke sleutel

    private String[] landen; //2 landen van de wedstrijd

    private int dag; //dag van de wedstrijd

    private int uur; //uur van de wedstrijd

    public Wedstrijd() {
    }
```

Comment: If you need any other to be able te help, feel free to ask.

Comment: You did not include the complete error message. Edit your question to include it, especially any `Caused by:` sections.

Comment: The error says failed in creating "Wedstrijd" table. Where is the bean/code for that table?

Comment: In the SpringWorldCupApplication class, in the same folder.

Comment: I found than in my Wedstrijd class, if I put the annotation @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) in comment, the error dissepears, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check application.properties file details.

```
#Connection url for the database "netgloo_blog"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
#Username and password
spring.datasource.username = SYSTEM
spring.datasource.password = SYSTEM
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

If all details are correct but you are getting same exception then update configuration for update.

**spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update**